# How to compare 2 List<string> objects to get the missing value from the List<string>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I use the "NOT IN" to get the missing data, to be added to "foo" List.

```
var accessories = new List<string>(); 
var foo = new List<string>();

accessories.Add("Engine");
accessories.Add("Tranny");
accessories.Add("Drivetrain");
accessories.Add("Power Window");

foo.Add("Engine");
foo.Add("Tranny");
foo.Add("Power Window");

foreach(var v in foo.Where(x => x??).???)
{
    foo.Add(v);  //Add the missing "Drivetrain" to it...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [List.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb908822(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
foo.AddRange(accessories.Except(foo));
```

From MSDN:

> Except Produces the set difference of two sequences.

Comment: You accidentally typed `Expect` and not `Except` in your MSDN quote ;)

Comment: @sab669 - I now fixed it here and on MSDN as well :)

Answer (score 5):

You can [use `.Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779) to get the difference between two sets:

```
var difference = accessories.Except(foo);
// difference is now a collection containing elements in accessories that are not in foo
```

If you then want to add those items to `foo`:

```
foo = foo.Concat(difference).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a LINQ method to do this for you, it looks like this; `accessories.Except(foo);`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `Concat` and `Distinct` to do this:

```
foo = foo.Concat(accessories).Distinct().ToList();
```

[image]

Edit: Or `Except` as others have pointed out, which seems to be the superior choice for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want foo to be the distinct combination of all elements in foo and accessories (i.e., the union of the two lists),

```
List<string> foo = foo.Union(accessories).ToList();
```

Comment: How does `Union` differ from `Distinct`? `Union Produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality comparer.` but I don't really understand the difference. For reference, `Distinct Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.`

Comment: Didn't works on a single set, so you would still have to have a step to join the two lists.  union produces the merged result, possibly by using distinct internally

Comment: should have said distinct works on a single set.  Stupid auto-correct