# Comparing two csv files and outputting values

Tags: c#, csv

I got two `.csv` files as shown below:

**1st file:**

```
"id"
4
1
3
```

**2nd file:**

```
"id"
1
2
3
4
5
```

I would like to check whether in first file there are all values from second file (no matter in which row they are). In my example in 1st file **2** and **5** values missing comparing to 2nd file so i would like to output somehow those values. How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare 2 List<string> objects to get the missing value from the List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763942/how-to-compare-2-liststring-objects-to-get-the-missing-value-from-the-liststr)

Comment: @DragandDrop and how to load it to lisdt firstly?

Comment: [How best to read a File into List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

Comment: Key word for find those where "not in" or "except" for the first link and "File to list string" for the second.

Comment: Load your CSV using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for example, and then you can work with your record lists as usual to perform comparison between them.

Comment: Question: Do you have a complete file and an incomplete one ? or Can both file be missing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know how to read them and don't know how to find out which are missing? You can use `Enumerable.Except`

```
IEnumerable<string> firstFileIds = GetFileIds(...);
IEnumerable<string> secondFileIds = GetFileIds(...);
IEnumerable<string> missingInFirst = secondFileIds.Except(firstFileIds);

Console.Write($"Missing in 1st file: {string.Join(",", missingInFirst)}");
```

Comment: Error: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'char'

Comment: Just additional question, do you know how to list duplicates out first list?

Comment: @Henry: `var dups=firstFileIds.GroupBy(id=>id).Where(g=>g.Count()>1).Select(g=>g.Key);`. Instead of `g.Count()>1` you can also use `g.Skip(1).Any()` since that could be more efficient